# How to change the layer selection view from Radio button to Image in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, maps, leaflet-draw

I have implemented the below example to show the multiple base layers of map in my application using LeafletJs.

[Leaflet JS LayerGroup example](https://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/)

I'm able to successfully implement the same but I'm trying to show same in a single tile image option.

Like for example I have two layers
1. Street Layer
2. Gray scale
With the above implementation in getting the below options on the map

[image: Map layer option]

Instead I'm trying to implement something like the the one below

[image]

So that when the user clicks on the small map icon, it should change the view to the other Layer. As in my case there will always be only two layer.

I have tried to add the pane option but that doesn't seem to be the right option for this behavior. Also I have tried some of the properties mentioned in the below link.

[Layer group documentation](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#layergroup)

Is this feasible with the existing components of Leaflet?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user, please be sure to take the [tour] to learn about this site's focused Q&A format.

Comment: The Layers Control is pretty easy to emulate in your own code - given 2 base layers, add one to the map whilst removing the other and vice versa.

Comment: @peeebeee you mean on a certain user event i should add / remove the layer. But issue is, instead of the radio button panel i want to show a single image. 
If the user is on A view, the image should show B view, and when the user clicks on the image it should change from A -> B and the image tile from B->A